# ¿cómo evitar volver (back) del navegador al cerrar de sesion?

Tags: php, html, html5, javascript

Duante mi búsqueda, no lo encontré algún código eficiente. Si un usuario quiere cerrar la sesión pero al refrescar entonces aparece de nuevo al sitio conectada. Quiero evitar al "volver" back o refrescar. ¿es posible?

mi codigo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay que colocar algo más algún javascript u php? prefiero en codigo PHP...
gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esta función te destruye toda tu sesión:

```
function destroySession() {

    $_SESSION = [];

    if (ini_get('session.use_cookies')) {

        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(),
                  '',
                  time() - 42000,
                  $params['path'],
                  $params['domain'],
                  $params['secure'],
                  $params['httponly']);
    }
    @session_destroy();
}
```

En tu fichero cerrar.php:

```
<?php 

require_once('todas_tus_funciones.php');

session_start();
destroySession();
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo agregaría esto inmediatamente después del `session_start()`:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Es decir, si se verifica que ya no tienes una sesión activa (porque en el cierre de sesión destruiste el campo `usuario` de la variable global `$_SESSION`) te redirigirá a `index.php` o a algún otro sitio que prefieras.

Puedes usar la misma lógica en aquellos ficheros que no deban ser accedidos si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión, y conforme avances en el conocimiento de manejo de sesiones, sabrás que hay maneras más refinadas de implementarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregar esto en la pagina.

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Este seria el codigo de la pagina que hace login, en mi caso se llama test2.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: AQUILES PEREZ
 * Date: 21/04/2016
 * Time: 08:19 AM
 */

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');

if(isset($_COOKIE['test'])){
    header("Location: inicio.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['crea'])){
    setcookie('test',"misession",null);
    header("Location: inicio.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="test" onclick="test()">test</button>
<script>
    function test(){
        document.location.href="test2.php?crea=1"
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Adicionalmente cuando te logeas rediriges a la pagina de inicio, donde tengo lo siguiente: Archivo Inicio.php:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Inicio la wea</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

He hecho la prueba y funciona. Saludos

Comment: no funciona, lo probe.

Comment: que raro a mi si me funciona, el header debes ponerlo antes de todo tu código.

Comment: lo estoy colocando arriba de estos codigos tampoco probando otras formas. Sigue igual. Lo intentaré otra forma de colocar correctamente.

Comment: prueba colocarlo en la página de login y en la página a la que rediriges después de loguearte.

Comment: Te paso un ejemplo mas completo espera.

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo te puse los dos archivo, puedes probarlo.

Comment: muchas gracias por su ayuda. Ahora ya se soluciono, debido por un problema de BD y mi colega lo hizo otra forma mas directa y cambio nuevas modificaciones. Uf, nada que una cosa no tiene que ver. Eso me hizo perder tiempo buscando...todas las maneras muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

si eliminas las cookies?

aqui un ejemplo de eliminar cookies

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember_user'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);
    unset($_COOKIE['HelloTest1']);
    setcookie('Hello', null, -1, '/');
    setcookie('HelloTest1', null, -1, '/');
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```